# PHP Query Breaking

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call a database for the first time in PHP, and this query is causing my code to break. Note that I've tested the connection to be good. The culprit is mysql_query(). Can anybody spot what might be going wrong? The table name is "users" and the entry under the 'Name' column is 'mvalentine'. Everything matches case as far as I can tell.

dbInit.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
$db = mysql_select_db('scaleup');
if ($db) {
    $user = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM 'users' WHERE 'Name' = 'mvalentine'");
}
else {
die ('Error 01: Connection to database failed.');
}

?>
```

This modified code is now returning something. The value 'users' in the ajax call is now returning "false"

The value being returned should be '1'

ajax response:

```
 <?php
include('dbInit.php');
include('objects.php'); //irrelevant, all code working properly

$layout = new Layout();
$bids = new Bids();
$out = array('layout' => $layout->_board, 'height' => $layout->_height, 'width' => $layout->_width,
                'bids' => $bids->_board, 'maxBids' => $bids- >_maxBids, 'users' => $user);
$out = json_encode($out);
echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in <b>C:\wamp\scaleUp\back\dbInit.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: Connection string is good. $db = true

Comment: oh yes I just saw that, weird enough, that error usually happens when the connection or query fails. Try `if (mysql_query(...))`?

Comment: Prove it by doing `mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE Name = 'mvalentine'", $connection);`

Comment: Just updated the code. $user is returning as "pass"...meaning the query is succesful???

Comment: You're not showing all code. The error references `json_encode()` which isn't even in your code.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions and learn about the much more powerful (and not depreciated) `mysqli` and `pdo` classes

Comment: Please update post to show the file names, since calls and error messages involve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting $user to contain the user ID, but it will actually contain a resource containing all of the rows returned. In order to get the user ID, you will need something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE `Name` = 'mvalentine'");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $user = $row['ID']; 
}
```

Also, take note of the other comments and answers regarding style and the preference of mysqli and PDO for this type of thing.

Comment: Ahh wicked, I will. This is awesome stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What is "$db" in your if statement?

To connect to your database you must use "mysql_connect" and "mysql_select_db".
For example,

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
    $db = mysql_select_db('database_name');
    if($connection)
    {
        if($db)
        {
            //query here
        } else {
            die("Couldn't connect to mysql database ".mysql_error());
        }
    } else {
        die("Couldn't connect to mysql host ".mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Also, it is good practice to surround table and column names with the prime character like so

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `column_name` = 'value'");
```

Comment: Oh, ok, then rename my variable $db to $database or whatever you want. You just need to make sure you connect to a database is all.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify this right now, but I believe you may have a syntax error in your query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM 'users' WHERE 'Name' = 'mvalentine'");
```

Column and table names, if you wish to quote them, should use the back tick:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE `Name` = 'mvalentine'");
```

Then change the rest of your code to actually fetch the user details:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE `Name` = 'mvalentine'") or die("Query failed");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$user = $row['ID'];
```

Comment: Ajax response --> <b>Warning</b>:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: type is unsupported, encoded as null in <b>C:\wamp\scaleUp\back\boardSetCGI.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />

Comment: With the regular single quotes, the response is 'false'

Comment: @valen That's because `$user` is assigned to the result of `mysql_query` and that's a resource; you still have to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on it like @jncraton described.